# BUG: launcher exited with 1 task remaining

Tags: selenium, protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

I got this issue and I could not solve this one,what can it be the problem,here is my protractor cucumber issue txt,and the Webdriver output.

Protractor:

protractor protractor.conf.js

protractor protractor.conf.js

```
(node:4416) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpd
ir() instead.
[19:28:55] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
[19:28:55] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[19:28:57] E/launcher - BUG: launcher exited with 1 tasks remaining
```

Webdriver selenium:

```
18:41:52.135 INFO - Done: [execute script: angular.resumeBootstrap(arguments[0])
;, [[protractorBaseModule_]]]
18:41:52.153 INFO - Executing: [delete session: 8524bd97-874b-4d90-9dcb-5e81556d
fdb2])
18:41:52.880 INFO - Done: [delete session: 8524bd97-874b-4d90-9dcb-5e81556dfdb2]

18:50:12.733 INFO - Session 35f119cd-c7b0-43a4-aa0d-a28b991b190c deleted due to
client timeout
18:50:13.466 INFO - Session 58c045bf-ee30-42c7-87f6-7676bfe6d04f deleted due to
client timeout
18:51:02.593 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName
=chrome}]])
18:51:02.596 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserNa
me=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30) on
port 3347
Only local connections are allowed.
18:51:03.718 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chro
me}]]
18:51:03.726 INFO - Executing: [set script timeout: 500000])
18:51:03.729 INFO - Done: [set script timeout: 500000]
18:51:03.747 INFO - Executing: [delete session: b16717b6-79f9-46e6-9746-886dc530
f165])
18:51:04.446 INFO - Done: [delete session: b16717b6-79f9-46e6-9746-886dc530f165]

18:54:06.400 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName
=chrome}]])
18:54:06.403 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserNa
me=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30) on
port 7437
Only local connections are allowed.
18:54:07.529 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chro
me}]]
18:54:07.541 INFO - Executing: [set script timeout: 500000])
18:54:07.544 INFO - Done: [set script timeout: 500000]
18:54:07.562 INFO - Executing: [delete session: fb75efb9-aa55-4a44-a9b5-1eab79be
56b8])
18:54:08.269 INFO - Done: [delete session: fb75efb9-aa55-4a44-a9b5-1eab79be56b8]

18:57:09.831 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName
=chrome}]])
18:57:09.833 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserNa
me=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30) on
port 39564
Only local connections are allowed.
18:57:10.961 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chro
me}]]
18:57:10.970 INFO - Executing: [set script timeout: 500000])
18:57:10.973 INFO - Done: [set script timeout: 500000]
18:57:10.992 INFO - Executing: [delete session: ad3c3147-b758-4ab2-95cb-aec1587f
77b4])
18:57:11.697 INFO - Done: [delete session: ad3c3147-b758-4ab2-95cb-aec1587f77b4]

18:58:10.168 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName
=chrome}]])
18:58:10.170 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserNa
me=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30) on
port 46887
Only local connections are allowed.
18:58:11.278 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chro
me}]]
18:58:11.289 INFO - Executing: [set script timeout: 500000])
18:58:11.294 INFO - Done: [set script timeout: 500000]
18:58:11.318 INFO - Executing: [delete session: 579e2dd0-a445-4770-83f8-5e031065
22cc])
18:58:12.029 INFO - Done: [delete session: 579e2dd0-a445-4770-83f8-5e03106522cc]

18:59:43.354 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName
=chrome}]])
18:59:43.358 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserNa
me=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30) on
port 42349
Only local connections are allowed.
18:59:44.470 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chro
me}]]
18:59:44.480 INFO - Executing: [set script timeout: 500000])
18:59:44.485 INFO - Done: [set script timeout: 500000]
19:03:49.350 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName
=chrome}]])
19:03:49.352 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserNa
me=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30) on
port 21593
Only local connections are allowed.
19:03:50.459 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chro
me}]]
19:03:50.468 INFO - Executing: [set script timeout: 500000])
19:03:50.471 INFO - Done: [set script timeout: 500000]
19:03:50.490 INFO - Executing: [delete session: 1be83e20-42ca-4f72-a7da-b31c5194
ad4f])
19:03:51.205 INFO - Done: [delete session: 1be83e20-42ca-4f72-a7da-b31c5194ad4f]

19:05:33.183 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName
=chrome}]])
19:05:33.187 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserNa
me=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30) on
port 24060
Only local connections are allowed.
19:05:34.301 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chro
me}]]
19:05:34.309 INFO - Executing: [set script timeout: 500000])
19:05:34.312 INFO - Done: [set script timeout: 500000]
19:07:47.499 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName
=chrome}]])
19:07:47.502 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserNa
me=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30) on
port 13582
Only local connections are allowed.
19:07:48.610 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chro
me}]]
19:07:48.622 INFO - Executing: [set script timeout: 500000])
19:07:48.625 INFO - Done: [set script timeout: 500000]
19:07:48.643 INFO - Executing: [delete session: 47aa2bda-41cf-4cd6-9443-9f448eb5
bffc])
19:07:49.361 INFO - Done: [delete session: 47aa2bda-41cf-4cd6-9443-9f448eb5bffc]

19:09:05.240 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName
=chrome}]])
19:09:05.243 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserNa
me=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30) on
port 39202
Only local connections are allowed.
19:09:06.369 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chro
me}]]
19:09:06.378 INFO - Executing: [set script timeout: 500000])
19:09:06.383 INFO - Done: [set script timeout: 500000]
19:09:06.404 INFO - Executing: [delete session: 1b0ab248-c539-4824-addf-72b52a5e
3c5b])
19:09:07.114 INFO - Done: [delete session: 1b0ab248-c539-4824-addf-72b52a5e3c5b]

19:09:32.034 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName
=chrome}]])
19:09:32.037 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserNa
me=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30) on
port 18240
Only local connections are allowed.
19:09:33.160 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chro
me}]]
19:09:33.168 INFO - Executing: [set script timeout: 500000])
19:09:33.172 INFO - Done: [set script timeout: 500000]
19:09:33.188 INFO - Executing: [delete session: 84996800-59ab-4a63-8138-bef9a4c9
7e33])
19:09:33.897 INFO - Done: [delete session: 84996800-59ab-4a63-8138-bef9a4c97e33]

19:11:24.409 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName
=chrome}]])
19:11:24.413 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserNa
me=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30) on
port 22183
Only local connections are allowed.
19:11:25.619 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chro
me}]]
19:11:25.629 INFO - Executing: [set script timeout: 500000])
19:11:25.632 INFO - Done: [set script timeout: 500000]
19:21:29.539 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName
=chrome}]])
19:21:29.542 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserNa
me=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30) on
port 1495
Only local connections are allowed.
19:21:30.786 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chro
me}]]
19:21:30.795 INFO - Executing: [set script timeout: 500000])
19:21:30.797 INFO - Done: [set script timeout: 500000]
19:22:58.350 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName
=chrome}]])
19:22:58.352 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserNa
me=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30) on
port 34511
Only local connections are allowed.
19:22:59.467 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chro
me}]]
19:22:59.510 INFO - Executing: [set script timeout: 500000])
19:22:59.580 INFO - Done: [set script timeout: 500000]
19:24:53.976 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName
=chrome}]])
19:24:53.980 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserNa
me=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30) on
port 16313
Only local connections are allowed.
19:24:55.114 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chro
me}]]
19:24:55.123 INFO - Executing: [set script timeout: 500000])
19:24:55.127 INFO - Done: [set script timeout: 500000]
19:26:10.069 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName
=chrome}]])
19:26:10.073 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserNa
me=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30) on
port 14874
Only local connections are allowed.
19:26:11.193 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chro
me}]]
19:26:11.202 INFO - Executing: [set script timeout: 500000])
19:26:11.206 INFO - Done: [set script timeout: 500000]
19:26:23.615 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName
=chrome}]])
19:26:23.618 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserNa
me=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30) on
port 30961
Only local connections are allowed.
19:26:24.732 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chro
me}]]
19:26:24.741 INFO - Executing: [set script timeout: 500000])
19:26:24.743 INFO - Done: [set script timeout: 500000]
19:26:35.575 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName
=chrome}]])
19:26:35.578 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserNa
me=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30) on
port 41164
Only local connections are allowed.
19:26:36.697 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chro
me}]]
19:26:36.711 INFO - Executing: [set script timeout: 500000])
19:26:36.714 INFO - Done: [set script timeout: 500000]
19:26:45.771 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName
=chrome}]])
19:26:45.774 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserNa
me=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30) on
port 12126
Only local connections are allowed.
19:26:46.890 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chro
me}]]
19:26:46.900 INFO - Executing: [set script timeout: 500000])
19:26:46.904 INFO - Done: [set script timeout: 500000]
19:26:47.137 INFO - Executing: [delete session: 90996b7e-9425-453f-a895-ff1a730a
610f])
19:26:47.899 INFO - Done: [delete session: 90996b7e-9425-453f-a895-ff1a730a610f]

19:27:25.790 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName
=chrome}]])
19:27:25.793 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserNa
me=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30) on
port 47793
Only local connections are allowed.
19:27:26.921 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chro
me}]]
19:27:26.931 INFO - Executing: [set script timeout: 500000])
19:27:26.935 INFO - Done: [set script timeout: 500000]
19:28:55.683 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName
=chrome}]])
19:28:55.685 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserNa
me=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30) on
port 23437
Only local connections are allowed.
19:28:56.805 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chro
me}]]
19:28:56.817 INFO - Executing: [set script timeout: 500000])
19:28:56.820 INFO - Done: [set script timeout: 500000]
19:32:14.360 INFO - Session e03be621-8cfc-41f4-b6bd-905037fb1d7d deleted due to
client timeout
19:38:15.104 INFO - Session 51b8ad4d-35b7-43e0-be3b-910eae3f1834 deleted due to
client timeout
19:44:15.827 INFO - Session 29865bea-461d-44df-85cd-64e1b2f51e63 deleted due to
client timeout
19:53:16.599 INFO - Session 0776f2e0-1237-4c47-871c-7a9aa2616246 deleted due to
client timeout
19:53:17.327 INFO - Session dc5fcdc6-c171-42b6-a503-718ef0e4dd52 deleted due to
client timeout
19:56:18.058 INFO - Session 7a6531f5-5201-49f6-813d-6ec737841eae deleted due to
client timeout
19:56:18.779 INFO - Session 99e3aab3-b1d1-444f-9b4c-83b310a95ad8 deleted due to
client timeout
19:59:19.508 INFO - Session 8dbeddea-290f-47f9-9ed3-7dae5a899e5f deleted due to
client timeout
19:59:20.234 INFO - Session 7540d4d1-9dfd-4258-9d59-bf50824dad7d deleted due to
client timeout
19:59:20.908 INFO - Session 5cefe9cc-b642-477f-a661-2066ad9f0bbb deleted due to
client timeout
19:59:21.582 INFO - Session 46bc6a99-9266-48aa-8ab5-9e962f3cb050 deleted due to
client timeout
13:37:53.738 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName
=chrome}]])
13:37:53.754 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserNa
me=chrome}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30) on
port 42981
Only local connections are allowed.
13:37:54.889 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=chro
me}]]
13:37:54.902 INFO - Executing: [set script timeout: 500000])
13:37:54.906 INFO - Done: [set script timeout: 500000]
```

Please help me,what must I do? - npm version is 5.3.0 - node version 8.0.0 - protractor version 4.0.13

Comment: Hmm your webdriver log starts at 18:41, runs to 19:59, then goes back down to 13:37 so that looks like 2 days of logs...?  Can you just start a new session and post that instead please?

Comment: Hi Gunderson!

Okay I am doing now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BUG: launcher exited with 1 task remaining protractor cucumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814165/bug-launcher-exited-with-1-task-remaining-protractor-cucumber)