# Protractor not installed now with npm

Tags: protractor, cucumber

I tried to install the protractor globally with `npm install -g protractor`

Here is the error message,I got it in every case.
I installed globally the protractor before,and worked well.

```
npm WARN   errno: -4048,
npm WARN   code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN   syscall: 'lstat',
npm WARN   path: 'c:\\x\\y\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\web
driver-manager\\node_modules' }
npm ERR! path c:\x\y\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\.webdriver-man
ager.DELETE\selenium\chromedriver_2.26.exe
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'c:\x\y\npm\node_modu
les\protractor\node_modules\.webdriver-manager.DELETE\selenium\chromedriver_2.26
.exe'
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'c:\x\y\npm\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\.webdriver-manager.DELETE\selenium\chromedriver_2
.26.exe'
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'c:\x\y\npm\node
_modules\protractor\node_modules\.webdriver-manager.DELETE\selenium\chromedriver
_2.26.exe'
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!      path: 'c:\\x\\y\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\
.webdriver-manager.DELETE\\selenium\\chromedriver_2.26.exe' },
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'c:\\x\\y\
\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\.webdriver-manager.DELETE\\seleniu
m\\chromedriver_2.26.exe\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'c:\\x\\y\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\.we
bdriver-manager.DELETE\\selenium\\chromedriver_2.26.exe',
npm ERR!   parent: 'protractor' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     c:\x\y\local\npm-cache\_logs\2017-08-22T15_38_20_888Z-debug.log
```

I can not do anything to this.
Is there any idea to this one.

Comment: did you tried running the command as administrator as suggested in log ?

Comment: Yes I run as admin.
It makes me nervous.

Comment: Any other idea?

Comment: well you can do 1) manully delete this "webdriver-manager.DELETE" from node_modules and they try again, 2) check log file "c:\x\y\local\npm-cache\_logs\2017-08-22T15_38_20_888Z-debug.log" for more details if there is any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you download and install NPM make sure you have the latest version.
Open your command prompt and type this. This might take a while to install.

> npm install npm@latest -g

Or this try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412129/how-do-i-update-node-and-npm-on-windows)

After checking your npm version with this command

> npm --version

type this to install protractor

> npm install -g protractor

Then check if protractor was successfully installed by checking the version you have

> protractor --version

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like due to the caching. Clear you cache before installing

```
npm cache clean
npm install -g protractor
```

If above command won't help then delete entire `.webdriver-manager.DELETE` directory from your_path/.../node_modules/ and issue again above two commands.

Answer (score 0):

`npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'c:\x\y\npm\node_modu
les\protractor\node_modules\.webdriver-manager.DELETE\selenium\chromedriver_2.26`

Is there any running chromedriver.exe on Windows Task Manager. If answer is yes, kill and try again